# How can I convert php string value to android string value?

Tags: php, android

```
public static String ConnDB() throws ParseException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String webAddress = "http://10.0.0.1:8080/jspbook/AppStore/NewFile.php";
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(webAddress);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet); 
    String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());                   
    Log.d("res", responseBody);
    return responseBody;
}
```

Above is part of android code. I checked this code getting resopnse from php server without problem. 
 
However, emulator not only received values from php, but also received all the php code which I dont 
need.

$time = "test time";
$grade = "test grade";
$title = "test title";
$content = "test content";

    echo ( "$time " );
    echo ( "$grade " );
    echo ( "$title " );
    echo ( "$content " );
    echo("abc");
?>

I only need value of $time , $grade , $title, $content but my emulator gets all the php code.

so.. my question is.. How can I convert php String $time to android java String time?

Comment: No, you'd need a PHP interpreter to parse the PHP script. You should have your server properly configured to execute the PHP code and then return that to your application (likely in JSON or some other serializable form)

Comment: If you are getting actual PHP code in response to an HTTP request, then your web server is not setup properly. Or am I misunderstanding your situation? I assume you want the PHP code to dynamically generate some values for your Java code to act on.

Comment: yes.. your assumtion is right. I didnt installed any php plugin yet to my eclipse. so... the reason I am getting actual PHP code is becuase I dont have proper PHP interpreter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your server doesnt support php well. Instead of giving u plain php text you should get html output.

BTW: Did u forget the < ? php in your script?

Comment: <? php is included in php but I didnt included here by mistake. yeah.. I need to google php interpreter for apache server now